# how to set ringer volume to 0 in objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to set ringer volume to 0 in objective c for iOS 9 .

Comment: No.  The closest you can get is to show a volume control and let the user do it.  You can also just not play any sounds.  You have zero control over the system ring volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a closed ecosystem. You cannot change device settings within a app. All you can control is your apps volume settings. Or you can ask user, provide a nice UI to mute the device manually. But you can absolutely not change the system ringer volume.